# AngularJS Patch Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

Hi I am trying to send `PATCH` request to ServiceStack from AngularJS, getting this error:

> Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

This are the request headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: PATCH
Origin: 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: https://pankajb1.dev.ma.net/ui/static/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

This is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.959 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 25 Sep 2015 20:23:51 GMT
```

Comment: Seems that the server is not allowing PATCH requests as you can see in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

Answer (score 2):

The `CorsFeature` by default didn't allow PATCH (it [will in next v4.0.48 release](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/5b0408c784afca5b5b390a8c8f4c738f38d8d7e6)).

In the meantime you can specify which methods should be available for CORS when registering the `CorsFeature`, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
    allowedMethods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"));
```